# No free space for SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, delete-list

Today we have received a below message for our SPonline environment:

No free space. This site is out of storage space and changes can't be saved. To free up space, delete files you don't need and empty the recycle bin.

1. I have deleted everything in recycle bin and still receive the message.
2. Tried to delete list or libraries but it wouldn't let me.
3. Tried to use PnP/Powershell to force to delete and it wouldn't let me.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try as following:

1. Decrease the Number of File Versions in SharePoint Online.

   Navigate to the Documents library/List and from **Settings** menu click **Library settings/List settings**>Versioning settings>modify the **Keep the following number of major versions value** to less.
2. Go to site information>view all site settings>Storage Metrics>select any file>click the Version History option to see all its saved versions.
   [image]
   Finally click Delete All versions to remove all the previous versions (except the current one), or delete one by one the versions you want, by selecting the Delete option in down-arrow options of each saved version.
   [image]

More information:

https://www.wintips.org/fix-sharepoint-running-out-of-space-office-365/